как удалить pgadmin4 Ubuntu 22.04
как удалить pgadmin4 Ubuntu 22.04

Удаление пакета pgadmin4
sudo apt remove pgadmin4

Удаление пакета pgadmin4 вместе с конфигурационными файлами
sudo apt purge pgadmin4

